# setting achartengine x-axis using array

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm new in using achartengine and I'm trying to implement it on my android app. What I'm trying to do is to set the x-axis using array.

i.e

String[] titles = new String[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12}

then the chart will appear like

y-axis

6

5

4

3

2

1
  2    4    6    8    10    12  x-axis = titles

in other words the x-axis value will depend in what the list of item that my array has.

anyone have thoughts how to do this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AChartEngine has a good way to deal with nice labels. You can indicate an approximate number of labels you want to have displayed on the X and Y axis and it will display the best number of nice numbers labels:

```
renderer.setXLabels(approximateNumberOfLabels);
renderer.setYLabels(approximateNumberOfLabels);
```

If that is not enough then you can add your own custom labels that can be any `String` values:

```
renderer.addXTextLabel(x, "label");
```